# creating a list using linq that is a subset of another list

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am trying to use Linq (C#) to create a List that is a subset of another list where the value to be queried (from a textbox) is between to values of the list object:

Here is my code

```cs
filteredMaps = allMaps
    .Where(map =>
         map.BeginningValue.CompareTo( textValueFilter.Text.Trim().ToUpper() ) <= 0
         && 
         map.EndingValue.CompareTo( textValueFilter.Text.Trim().ToUpper() ) >=0
    )
    .ToList();
```

`filteredMaps` is always empty after executing this code.   I think I need a 'select' clause in there somewhere, but haven't figured out the syntax.

I am new to Linq (and lamdas)

map is an object of type MapEntry that is (partially) defined as

```
public readonly string BeginningValue;
public readonly string EndingValue;
```

allMaps and filteredMaps are both defined as `List<MapEntry>`

I have tried the following code with the same result:

```cs
IEnumerable<MapEntry> mapEntries = (
    from map in allMaps
    where (
        map.BeginningValue.CompareTo( textValueFilter.Text.Trim().ToUpper() ) <= 0
        &&
        map.EndingValue.CompareTo( textValueFilter.Text.Trim().ToUpper()) >= 0 )
    select map
);

filteredMaps = mapEntries.ToList();
```

As stuartd and jmcilhinney pointed out, my CompareTo was defective.  The following code worked:

```
string filter = textValueFilter.Text.Trim().ToUpper();
            
            IEnumerable<MapEntry> mapEntries = (from map in (IEnumerable<MapEntry>)allMaps
                            where(map.BeginningValue.Substring(0,filter.Length).CompareTo(filter) <= 0
             && map.EndingValue.Substring(0,filter.Length).CompareTo(filter) >= 0) select map);
            filteredMaps = mapEntries.ToList();
```

Since I know that BeginningValue and EndingValue will always be all uppercase, I was able to simplify, but I will keep a note on

Comment: Can you add a bit of sample data that reproduces the problem to your question? An example map, and an example filter would be ideal.

Comment: The value of textValueFilter.Text = "E".
I have the following values in allMaps:

BeginningValue  /   EndingValue :
E0100              /      E0100

Comment: No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. Update your question and provide the FULL and CLEAR explanation that you should have in the first place, which must include a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: `"E0100".CompareTo("E")` is `1`

Comment: The code you have works exactly as it should. Based on your example, it is your expectations and/or understanding of how `String.CompareTo` works that is at fault.

Comment: OT: If you want to do a case-insensitive comparison then do that. Don't use `ToUpper` or `ToLower`. In this case, `map.BeginningValue.CompareTo(textValueFilter.Text.Trim().ToUpper())` should be `string.Compare(map.BeginningValue, textValueFilter.Text.Trim(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)`. Also, don't use the same long expression over and over. You should be creating the final filter value once and assigning that to a variable, then using that variable multiple times.

Comment: If the `BeginningValue` and `EndValue` are both `"E0100"` then the only value that is within that range is `"E0100"` so that's the only value you could enter to match that range. `"E"` is not in that range so why would it match? Either your explanation is accurate and the code already works exactly as it should or your explanation is not accurate. If you think that `"E"` should be within that range, you need to explain exactly what rules you want to implement to make that the case, because it's not based normal "alphanumeric" rules.

Comment: Thanks jmcilhinney and stuartd for your quick responses.  As you pointed out the fault was in my use oc CompareTo.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. But if you want the `BeginningValue` and `EndingValue` to include the textbox string, use the following method:

```
var filteredMaps = mapEntries.Where(map =>
        map.BeginningValue.ToUpper().Contains(textValueFilter.Text.ToUpper()) 
             &&
        map.EndingValue.ToUpper().Contains(textValueFilter.Text.ToUpper()) 
 ).ToList();
```

If you want the `BeginningValue` and `EndingValue` to be equal to the text box string:

```
var filteredMaps = mapEntries
.Where(map =>
      map.BeginningValue.Equals(textValueFilter.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) 
       &&
      map.EndingValue.Equals(textValueFilter.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) 
      ).ToList();
```